# CSS transitions initial state bug

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog, css-transitions

I've created a CSS transition for an overlay that appears from the right hand side of the screen on a click event. It works except that it first shoots across the screen on initial click on anywhere. It's initial position is off the screen to the right:

```
.form_div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 25%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 150%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 2em;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

The transition that makes it appear is:

```
.show-form-div {
  left:71%;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9yw4f/)

Where is the bug appearing from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it happens because your starting state has the `dark-overlay` shown.  Therefore the first `click` is triggering on the `.dark-overlay` div, NOT the `#xmarksthespot` div.

You need to start out with:

```
<div class="dark_overlay hide-modal"></div>
```

See [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/9yw4f/21/) to your fiddle